# same table data rowspan html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, datatable

i got stuck when im try to build a table with data like this

```
export const arr = [
{no : '1',
name: 'george',
fruit: 'orange'},
{no : '2',
name: 'jason',
fruit: 'orange'},
{no : '3',
name: 'david',
fruit: 'apple'},]
```

i want to rowspan when the data same with data index -1

```
import arr from './constant'

<table>
<tr>
<th>no</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>fruit</th>
</tr>
{arr.map((el)=>(
<tr>
<td>{el.no}</td>
<td>{el.name}</td>
<td rowspan={?????????}>{el.fruit}</td>
</tr>
))}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using vanilla JavaScript? I made the code in react.js.
You can check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-hellman-mguw2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: this is so helping me! thank you. im using react.js too

Comment: hey, can you solve this? please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872995/html-table-rowspan-in-reactjs

Comment: @DickaReynaldi, please accept my answer if I helped you. I will provide the solution for next question. Thanks.

Comment: i already accept your answer. thank you in advance if you want to help me for the next question.

Comment: thanks a lot. I pushed my answer for next question. please check that question.